# GET request works with postman but not with python requests and curl

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, postman, urllib

I have tried to create a specific GET request in python to the site :
https://sgfm.elcorteingles.es/SGFM/dctm/MEDIA03/202006/24/00117731276964____5__210x210.jpg

But I dont get any response from the browser and its keep waiting forever.
then I tried to create a curl request and same thing happens(keeps waiting forever).
After all that, I tried to create a POSTMAN request and it works perfect! And I did not understood why it works with postman but not with python and curl as all these platforms are not browser like.
I used the postman method to convert postman request to python and curl:

```
#python
import requests

url = "https://sgfm.elcorteingles.es/SGFM/dctm/MEDIA03/202006/24/00117731276964____5__210x210.jpg"

payload = {}
headers= {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, json = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

```
#curl

curl --location --request GET 'https://sgfm.elcorteingles.es/SGFM/dctm/MEDIA03/202006/24/00117731276964____5__210x210.jpg'
```

but they both not getting any response.
Does anyone know why this is happening and convert it to a python request? or even curl I can handle that too.

Comment: you have to make use of `requests.get(url, ...)` instead of `requests.request()`

Comment: the website/server is blocking calls from curl/requests etc. as the client.

Comment: @FishingCode what difference does it makes when using .get() over .request("url", ...)?

Answer (score 11):

Your headers do not get accepted by the server. I tried with these and it works for me.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
```

Also, you need to change the request you make to that the `requests.requests('GET')` is not a proper way of making a `GET` request. The proper one is `requests.get(url)`. They are the same methods, but for cleaner code you should stick to `requests.get(url)`

```
import requests

url = "https://sgfm.elcorteingles.es/SGFM/dctm/MEDIA03/202006/24/00117731276964____5__210x210.jpg"

payload = {}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: only `User-Agent` header is needed. others can be skipped.

Comment: @Aleksander Ikleiw It worked once for me and then I got a 403 error

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw Can I do anything about this block?

Comment: @lby your IP might be blocked or the server does not accept requests from your IP. try to use proxy.

Comment: ```"Also, you need to change the request you make to that the requests.requests('GET') is not a proper way of making a GET request. The proper one is requests.get(ur;)"```

@AleksanderIkleiw Why is that? What difference would it make if we use requests.request('GET')? I get the same result when I use any of those methods.

Comment: @sxddhxrthx he's wrong on this one - `requests.request(method="GET")` is the same thing

Comment: @MichałZawadzki I have pointed out that as a wrong approach, because `requests.get())` is much cleaner, which is key in many projects.

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw yes but cleaner is not the same as wrong. I appreciate your edit taking that into consideration. 

To give an example where `requests.request()` might be required, imagine you want to allow users to call an endpoint, but make it easier for them. So you expose this:

```def simple_request(url, method, headers):
    if method == "POST" and "x-csrf-token" not in headers:
        token = _get_xcsrf_token()
        headers["x-csrf-token"] = "fetch"
    requests.request(url=url, headers=headers, method=method)
``` 
... and so on, basically abstracting away the inner logic

Answer (score 0):

Might be headers but might also be that Postman uses a system proxy. Set the same proxy in python using either

```
url = "https://example.com"
headers = {'User-Agent':...}
proxies = {"https":"<same postman proxy>"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```

or

```
url = "https://example.com"
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies.update({"https":"<same postman proxy>"})
s.headers.update({"User-Agent":...})
s.get(url)
```